# How to get WiFi router information?

Tags: javascript, wifi, router

Is there a way I can get WiFi router information (mac address, ip address, and other if possible) of the WiFi router I am connected to using javascript?
Preferred browser: chrome 
If it's not possible, what are my options?

Comment: Other than the external IP address, you can't do that.

Comment: how do I get external IP?

Comment: you can use ajax to talk to the control panel, basically scraping the html and forging form requests, but it will be hard-coded for just a single router family... something like ajax("//192.168.1.1", mycb)

Comment: @dandavis: No; same-origin policy.

Comment: @SLaks: greasemonkey or tampermonkey can launch from the login page... also, some routers even provide an api for remote managment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't any web browser API to get any local network connection information such as local router address, mac, etc.

Comment: What about other programming languages? C++, Javascript, Python or bash or powershell?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a modem bought at Orange (I don't know if there is Orange in your country), you can use any browser (Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, Torch, etc...) go on the website 192.168.1.1, username and password are both 'admin' then you will find all the info about the router (only if you are connected to it, of course)

Comment: Per http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior, do not add signatures to your posts, and avoid self-promotion.  I've edited the unnecessary information out of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things which you can check:

Using Java (with a signed applet)
Using signed Js, which in FireFox (Mozilla) gets higher privileges than normal JS (but it is quite complicated)