# Is it possible to detect an Ubiquiti UniFi Security Gateway with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, security, firewall, gateway

Since the Ubiquiti UniFi Security Gateway has some very specific standard settings that cause problems on our website (which can also have a different reason), I would like to check with JavaScript if there is one present and show a guide accordingly.

[How to get WiFi router information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549337/how-to-get-wifi-router-information) explains that it is not possible to identify it directly. But maybe it's possible to identify it indirectly by certain characteristics?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get WiFi router information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549337/how-to-get-wifi-router-information)

Comment: Good question. If it is necessary to get the information directly, then yes - it is not possible. But is it possible indirectly perhaps?